# What is reason of app crash on some android device

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception

My app is crashing on some devices and while it works fine on others. One of my application's users sent me this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(132710400bytes) bitmap.
        at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17099)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16081)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16865)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3766)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3552)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16076)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16865)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3766)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3552)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16076)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16865)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3766)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3552)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16076)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16865)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3766)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3552)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16076)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16865)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3766)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3552)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16076)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16865)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3766)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3552)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17102)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:754)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16081)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:666)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:672)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:780)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2840)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2648)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2255)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1290)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6399)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:873)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:685)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:859)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

My Questions are:

What is this error and why is it device specific?

Why did it occur and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you using high resolution images? if yes some devices with small resolution won't handle it. Please segregate your images as per the resolution. Put then as per the resolution inside drawable-dpi, drawable-dpi, drawabletxhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and drawable-xxxhdpi. Devices takes the images from these folders as per their resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago. Reduce the size of your PNG resources or use Vectors instead if possible!

You could use some online tool like [this one](https://onlinepngtools.com/resize-png) to perform the size reduction.